# Site works in Firefox and IE, but not on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-chrome, wamp

My local Wordpress site works in IE and Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome because Chrome is adding 'https' to some of the URL's for my stylesheets, scripts, and images. If I view the source files in IE or Firefox, the URL's start with http://localhost/my_site/, but in Chrome it looks like https://localhost/my_site/

I've tried everything to figure out why it's only happening in Chrome and I'm completely stumped. I've emptied the cache, I've tried running in Incognito mode, I've tried disabling all my extensions, I've disabled my Firewall, but I can't get it to work.

Help!

Comment: What happens if you go to [http://localhost:80/my_site/](http://localhost:80/my_site/) in Chrome?

Comment: @colin, the same thing happens. No difference

Comment: You probably already did this, but did you try disabling all Chrome extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is an [HTTP STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) issue. Try this in Chrome:

- Go to: chrome://net-internals/#hsts
- Go to the bottom of the page and find the QUERY domain textbox and enter localhost
- If localhost in there, put it in the delete textbox to get rid of it

Source: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444479#c7

Comment: I tried that solution previously and there is still no change in the way Chrome is parsing the URL's.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is weird. I don't know what is causing that issue, but I can tell you how to fix it.

Open the .htaccess file and add this block of code:

```
#   Force Non-HTTPS:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```